# p:selectOneMenu cuts off in modal dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `selectOneMenu` dropdown in a modal dialog. In order for the dropdown list to move along with the dialog when scrolling the page I have set `appendTo="@this"` for the `selectOneMenu`, but this causes the dropdown list to be cut off at the edge of the dialog.

How could I achieve both that the dropdown of selectOneMenue is anchored to the dialog and that the list is not cut off at the edge of the dialog?

Comment: a modal dialog fixes the outbound screen and should be sized not to be necessary to scroll the screen.

Comment: Read about css and overflow. And read about [ask] and [mcve]